# Kerberos/NIS users require shadow hack

Tags: pam, kerberos

If I have a Ubuntu system to use Kerberos for authentication and NIS for information, users cannot log in unless I copy the content of my NIS shadow map to /etc/shadow.  They get insta-rejected.

If I run `getent shadow` with an unpopulated /etc/shadow, I do not see the content of my NIS shadow map.

So how do I A) make `getent shadow` return the contents of the NIS map; or B) make PAM not care that I don't have shadow information for Kerberos/NIS users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to enable the `broken_shadow` functionality for the pam_unix.

In `/etc/pam.d/common-account`, find the pam_unix line and add `broken_shadow` to the end of it:

```
account [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]        pam_unix.so  broken_shadow
```

Description:

> Some network setups include 'x' in a crypted password field, but have
>   no shadow information. When this happens, pam_unix fails account
>   management because it can't read this information. A 'brokenshadow'
>   option assumes that errors reading the information mean that it
>   doesn't exist, and allows the user to log in.